# Re-positioning the Google branding logo make it smaller on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to reposition the Google Branding logo on my Android Application but whenever I tried to reposition it, the size of the logo decreases.

I want to reposition it to the upper left corner of the screen.

I am using the below code to reposition it.

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
    rlMap.getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
    googleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, rect.height() - 50);
```

How can I resize the google logo and increase its size?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the google logo on the upper left side using this code. Set this code in onMapReady function.

```
try {
    View googleLogo = mapLayout.findViewWithTag("GoogleWatermark");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams glLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) googleLogo.getLayoutParams();
    glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
    glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    glLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, 0);
    googleLogo.setLayoutParams(glLayoutParams);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Can't find watermark name. Error: ", e);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Surprise!!, I use it in my project. See my updated answer.

Comment: Not working in my size Actually my parent layout contains more layout 
Is that the reason?

Comment: There is no interaction with your layout to change the google logo position.

Comment: Then I don't know why It's working on one screen and not on another screen